# Bibliography as unnumbered section

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, natbib, unnumbered-sections

I am using `memoir` class and would like to have unnumbered **References** (with this title instead of Bibliography) at the end of each chapter.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright, twoside, a4paper, chapter=TITLE]{memoir}
\usepackage[sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
    \section{One section, please}
    This is just a dumb text to fill this space and make an example. Ok, I have not enough creativity to keep creating text. What about doing copy paste? So that is what I am going to do. Blah blah blah...

    Here I should cite some author. Let's cite Einstein! \cite{einstein1935can}

    \section{Another section, please}
    This is just a dumb text to fill this space and make an example. Ok, I have not enough creativity to keep creating text. What about doing copy paste? So that is what I am going to do. Blah blah blah...

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{_bib}
    

\end{document}
```

This is the `_bib.bib` file content:

```
@article{einstein1935can,
    title       = {Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
    author      = {Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
    journal     = {Physical review},
    volume      = {47},
    number      = {10},
    pages       = {777},
    year        = {1935},
    publisher   = {APS}
    }
```

Any one, please help?